# Alternative program to ogr2ogr

Tags: convert, ogr2ogr, software-recommendations

Is there an alternative program to ogr2ogr when trying to convert file formats?
I've played around with ogr2ogr quite a bit lately (on Windows) but I can't get around some issues ..
For example when converting shapefile to geojson it destroys the attribute table due to the wrong encoding format. Specifying it won't help either because this feature doesn't seem to work on Windows machines ..

So I'm getting tired of this program and want to use something different. And I don't want to use QGIS, because it takes a lot of time to start and I don't want to wait 5 minutes to convert just a single file ..

Do you know any alternatives? It needs to run offline, so no web services.

Comment: An alternative is to ask a question in gis.stackexchange about how tho convert your data into geojson with ogr2ogr on Windows and attach some sample data. One popular commercial alternative is FME, which, by the way, is internally using GDAL for some conversions.

Comment: And if QGis is slow to start, you can buy other software... (or uninstall some plugins..)